# passing javascript object to function in a jquery way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

Yeah so I've been messing around with javascript a while but only recently got into stuff like object orientation, prototyping and using objects for all functions and vars.

But, many frameworks like jQuery or extJS have something I have yet to grasp, you can define an object by using a built in function for searching the dom, example:

```
var a = $('#mydiv');
```

and then you can do a.click(function);

So my question is, how can I create a "framework" of sorts where I can write code in that style, like example:

```
var mydiv = document.querySelector('mydiv');
mydiv.neph(args,args);
```

So I have my object defined, in this case it's a dom element or whatever, now I pass it to my function "neph" with arguments, I want to create code that allows me to do this. But since mydiv does not have any function, it only has in this case the dom element right so mydiv.neph does not exist, but in jquery you can define whatever var and .click or .mouseover or whatever does exists within the object as functions? Confusion ensues! :D

Ok sorry if this is a retarded question btw =P

Comment: You should check out the jQuery source code as as starter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery and other libraries define a function called `$` that takes several optional parameters.  The object returned by calling `$` is not a DOM element, but a jQuery object wrapping a DOM element up with a set of convenient functions.

You can do something similar yourself:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <input id="derp" type="text"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

function $(id)
{
   return new myLibrary(id);
};

function myLibrary(id)
{
   this.el = document.getElementById(id);
};

myLibrary.prototype.help = function()
{
   alert(this.el.id);
   return this;
};

// Woah! My own fake jquery!
$("derp").help();
</script>

   </body>
</html>
```

jQuery is far more sophisticated, of course.  For example, it will use [apply and call](http://www.google.com/search?&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript+apply+call) to set `this` correctly in calls like `jQuery.each`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Prototype in javascript. This is what allows you to add a function to an object that's already defined (i.e. the .click() function that you gave as an example).

You can have a look at the [jQuery code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js), it's open source. It's not the simplest code, but you can still see how it works and how they do it.

Answer (score 1):

Mike's comment is a good answer: Look at jquery or Ext-Core's sources.

Maybe what you're missing is that, in jquery, for instance $() returns a *jquery object*, which wraps the plain vanilla DOM node, providing extended functionality.

Comment: Yes, and the `click` and other jQuery functions are part of the jQuery object, rather than the HTML element object. Use a debugger like Firebug or Web Inspector, and look at what the `$()` function returns, if youre interested.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, `$` is just an alias to the `jQuery` object. So when you call `$('#mydiv');` you're really calling a function like `jQuery('#mydiv');` So part of what makes jQuery so cool is that every the `$()` function returns `this`, which means when you call the `$()` you're getting a handle to the jQuery object and all of the methods it has on it. That is what allows you to do something like this:

```
var a = $('#mydiv');
a.click(function() { // etc etc etc });
```

So to pull off your example:

```
var mydiv = document.querySelector('mydiv');
mydiv.neph(args,args);
```

You'd have to create an object that has a function called `neph` on it and return that object in the context of `mydiv` when you call querySelector.

```
var myFramework = function() {
  this.context = undefined;
  this.neph = function(arg, args) {
    console.log(arg, args);
  }
};

var myCuteFunction = function(element) {
  var f = new myFramework();
  f.context = element;
  return f;
}

// ...

var x = myCuteFunction('#mydiv');
x.neph(arg, args);
```

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense, actually quite easy once you see it clearly :D but the jquery code has a bunch of stuff not exactly easy felt like searching for a needle in a haystack

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has really answered about Ext, you can easily extend the element wrapper prototype:

```
Ext.override(Ext.Element, {
    myMethod: function(a, b){
        console.log(a, b, this);
    }

});
```

"this" will refer to the Ext.Element object.